# Sprite Kit on OS X - moving

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I have a question: what's the best practice to handle player input (to move a character) using Sprite Kit on OSX?

Is the best way to use a `switch-case` statement inside of `keyDown:` method, or is there a better way than a 200 line switch?

I ask because I had a bit of trouble with handling player input.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Back when Apple had their infamous adventure game online as an example of how to use SpriteKit, they indeed used the `keyDown` and `keyUp` methods. They even combined them into a single method to handle either case. In SKScene:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self handleKeyEvent:event keyDown:YES];
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self handleKeyEvent:event keyDown:NO];
}

- (void)handleKeyEvent:(NSEvent *)event keyDown:(BOOL)downOrUp {
    // First check the arrow keys since they are on the numeric keypad.
    if ([event modifierFlags] & NSNumericPadKeyMask) { // arrow keys have this mask
        NSString *theArrow = [event charactersIgnoringModifiers];
        unichar keyChar = 0;
        if ([theArrow length] == 1) {
            keyChar = [theArrow characterAtIndex:0];
            switch (keyChar) {
                case NSUpArrowFunctionKey:
                    self.defaultPlayer.moveForward = downOrUp;
                    break;
                case NSLeftArrowFunctionKey:
                    self.defaultPlayer.moveLeft = downOrUp;
                    break;
                case NSRightArrowFunctionKey:
                    self.defaultPlayer.moveRight = downOrUp;
                    break;
                case NSDownArrowFunctionKey:
                    self.defaultPlayer.moveBack = downOrUp;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Now check the rest of the keyboard
    NSString *characters = [event characters];
    for (int s = 0; s<[characters length]; s++) {
        unichar character = [characters characterAtIndex:s];
        switch (character) {
            case 'w':
                self.defaultPlayer.moveForward = downOrUp;
                break;
            case 'a':
                self.defaultPlayer.moveLeft = downOrUp;
                break;
            case 'd':
                self.defaultPlayer.moveRight = downOrUp;
                break;
            case 's':
                self.defaultPlayer.moveBack = downOrUp;
                break;
            case ' ':
                self.defaultPlayer.fireAction = downOrUp;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This was the code from their adventure game until they took it down from their servers (which, sadly, means you can't access it anymore). I've always assumed this was the best way to do it, since the Doc's recommend it, but I may be wrong. Also, I've never really had to handle input of > 200 different key presses like you say in the question. However, for games that use the typical wasd, spacebar, and some other keys, this has worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Thans. I want players to set their own movement settings and allow up to 4 players on single device without network play. Therefore I need to handle all of keys I can. I used solution based on NSArray that had index for each key and contained reference to object and selector that was performed. But some misterious problems appeared (if all characters were moving one of them was lagging until enyone pressed key), so I wonder if enumerating NSArray is the best practise. I also wonder if switch-case time complexity is O(1) even on RICS CPUs like in Apple TV. (Btw do you have the demo project? ty)